# gatsby index.html changes in git with every build

Tags: gatsby

It seems like gatsby is rebuilding my `index.html` file every time I run `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build`. I don't like that every new commit I make seems to rewrite my `index.html`, so I'm considering adding it to my `.gitignore`, but I can see how adding `index.html` to the `.gitignore` could be dangerous (maybe I'm misunderstanding and it's not be overwritten)?

Does anyone know why this happens or what can be done about it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directories `.cache/` and `public/` should be in your `.gitignore`.

Check out the [`.gitignore` of Gatsby's hello-world starter](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world/blob/master/.gitignore#L61).

Comment: That's odd. I do have that in my `.gitignore`, but when I try to recreate it, I can't reproduce the change. Thanks for your answer. If I am able to reproduce it, I'll share how.